# Access dictionaries values with dynamic keys

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

When I run the following task:

```yaml
- name: Get info about DVPG
  community.vmware.vmware_dvs_portgroup_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    validate_certs: no
  register: dvpg_var
```

It returns the following result:

```json
{
   "dvpg_var":{
      "changed":false,
      "dvs_portgroup_info":{
         "WIFI-NEPTUNE":[
            {
               "active_uplinks":[
                  "lag1"
               ],
               "description":null,
               "dvswitch_name":"WIFI-NEPTUNE",
               "key":"dvportgroup-3000",
               "mac_learning":{
                  "allow_unicast_flooding":null,
                  "enabled":false,
                  "limit":null,
                  "limit_policy":null
               },
               "network_policy":{
                  "forged_transmits":true,
                  "mac_changes":true,
                  "promiscuous":false
               },
               "num_ports":4,
               "port_allocation":"elastic",
               "port_binding":"static",
               "port_policy":{
                  "block_override":true,
                  "ipfix_override":false,
                  "live_port_move":false,
                  "network_rp_override":false,
                  "port_config_reset_at_disconnect":true,
                  "security_override":false,
                  "shaping_override":false,
                  "traffic_filter_override":false,
                  "uplink_teaming_override":false,
                  "vendor_config_override":false,
                  "vlan_override":false
               },
               "portgroup_name":"VLAN100",
               "standby_uplinks":[
                  
               ],
               "teaming_policy":{
                  "inbound_policy":true,
                  "notify_switches":true,
                  "policy":"loadbalance_srcid",
                  "rolling_order":false
               },
               "type":"earlyBinding",
               "vlan_info":{
                  
               }
            }
         ],
         "WIFI-SATURNO":[
            {
               "active_uplinks":[
                  "lag2"
               ],
               "description":null,
               "dvswitch_name":"WIFI-SATURNO",
               "key":"dvportgroup-3001",
               "mac_learning":{
                  "allow_unicast_flooding":null,
                  "enabled":false,
                  "limit":null,
                  "limit_policy":null
               },
               "network_policy":{
                  "forged_transmits":true,
                  "mac_changes":true,
                  "promiscuous":false
               },
               "num_ports":4,
               "port_allocation":"elastic",
               "port_binding":"static",
               "port_policy":{
                  "block_override":true,
                  "ipfix_override":false,
                  "live_port_move":false,
                  "network_rp_override":false,
                  "port_config_reset_at_disconnect":true,
                  "security_override":false,
                  "shaping_override":false,
                  "traffic_filter_override":false,
                  "uplink_teaming_override":false,
                  "vendor_config_override":false,
                  "vlan_override":false
               },
               "portgroup_name":"VLAN101",
               "standby_uplinks":[
                  
               ],
               "teaming_policy":{
                  "inbound_policy":true,
                  "notify_switches":true,
                  "policy":"loadbalance_srcid",
                  "rolling_order":false
               },
               "type":"earlyBinding",
               "vlan_info":{
                  
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I'm unable to find a way to iterate, loop or only retrieve the `portgroup_name` values.

I tried to do this:

```yaml
- name: Get portgroup_name list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info['WIFI-NEPTUNE'] | json_query('[*].portgroup_name') }}"
```

It works, but it's not what I need. Instead of specifying `dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info['WIFI-NEPTUNE']`, I want to iterate over the keys under `dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMESPath — the query language used by `json_query` — in order to give a wildcard for the dictionary key under `dvs_portgroup_info`:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info | json_query('*[*].portgroup_name[]')
```

*Note: the last `[]` is actually the [*flatten operator*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) of JMESPath and is there to flatten the list of list created by the lists under `WIFI-NEPTUNE` and `WIFI-SATURNO`.*

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info | json_query('*[*].portgroup_name[]')
  vars:
    dvpg_var:
      dvs_portgroup_info:
        WIFI-NEPTUNE:
          - portgroup_name: VLAN100
        WIFI-SATURNO:
          - portgroup_name: VLAN101
```

This yields

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  dvpg_var.dvs_portgroup_info | json_query('*[*].portgroup_name[]'):
  - VLAN100
  - VLAN101
```

Comment: I can't believe, it works perfectly. You are a magician @β.εηοιτ.βε, thans you very much. Could you recommend tips, web pages, documentation to improve my understanding of this topic?

Comment: @Bizargorri If you are speaking strictly about JMESPath, their tutorial is quite nice, each examples query and input are editable and you can play with the value to see how the result adapt. https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html